# Are there any Tools like Schematics (Python) for Java?

Tags: java, python, validation, serialization, schema

Are there similar tools to this neat Python library: https://github.com/j2labs/schematics in Java?

> Schematics is an easy way to model data. It provides mechanisms for structuring data, initializing data, serializing data, formatting data and validating data against type definitions, like an email address.
>
> ...
>
> Schematics' main goal is to provide similar functionality to a type system along with a way to generate the schematics we send to the Internet, or store in a database, or send to some Java process, or basically any use case with structured data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess JSR 303, *bean validation* would be the closest equivalent:

> Bean Validation defines a metadata model and API for JavaBean validation. The metadata source is annotations, with the ability to override and extend the meta-data through the use of XML validation descriptors. The Hibernate team provides with Hibernate Validator the reference implementation of Bean Validation and also created the Bean Validation TCK any implementation of JSR 303 needs to pass.

- http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303
- http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/